# Numpy Array Broadcast Subtraction

Tags: numpy

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,4,6],[2,4,6]])
cs = np.array([[5,5,5],[6,6,6]])
data - cs[:, np.newaxis]
```

`data` dimension 3x3
`cs` dimension 2x3
`cs[:, np.newaxis]` dimension 2x1x3
Can anybody explain how the subtraction works?

Comment: It's there in [this doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)?

Comment: What's the result shape?

Comment: A (3,3) broadcasts with a (2,3,1) to (1,3,3) (adding an initial dimension), and together to produce a (2,3,3) result (scaling all size 1 dimensions to match).